# Could not find class 'android.media.AudioAttributes$Builder'

Tags: java, android, api, audio, classloader

So I'm currently implementing playing sounds for a game I'm working on. Now the game supports API 8 to the latest 21. I'm using SoundPool to play and handle the sounds but it seems that with API 21, you have to set the AudioAttributes for SoundPool.

**I am currently getting the following error:**

> 05-15 13:56:48.202 
>   26245-26245/thedronegame.group08.surrey.ac.uk.thedronegame E/dalvikvm﹕
>   Could not find class 'android.media.AudioAttributes$Builder',
>   referenced from method
>   thedronegame.group08.surrey.ac.uk.thedronegame.Sound.initializeRecentAPISoundPool

**Sound Class**

```
<pre>package thedronegame.group08.surrey.ac.uk.thedronegame;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioAttributes;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by Michael on 19/03/15.
 */
public class Sound {

    /**
     * The sound pool
     */
    private SoundPool soundPool = null;


    /**
     * The current Sound.
     */
    private int sound = 0;

    /**
     * false Boolean.
     */
    private boolean loaded = false;

    /**
     * The context.
     */
    private Context context = null;

    /**
     * Audio Manager.
     */
    private AudioManager audioManager = null;

    /**
     * Literal Volume.
     */
    private float literalVolume = 0;

    /**
     * Maximum Volume.
     */
    private float maximumVolume = 0;

    /**
     * Volume.
     */
    private float volume = 0;

    /**
     * A constructor for creating a new Sound object
     */
    public Sound(Context context) {

        this.context = context;

        this.audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        // Set Literal Volume for Audio Manager.
        this.literalVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        // Set Maximum Volume for Audio Manager.
        this.maximumVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        // Set volume for GameSound Pool.
        this.volume = literalVolume / maximumVolume;
    }

    /**     
     * Initialize the SoundPool for later API versions
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void initializeRecentAPISoundPool() {
        // Create AudioAttributes.


        AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build();

        this.soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
                .setAudioAttributes(attributes)
                .setMaxStreams(7)
                .build();
    }

    /**     
     * Intialize SoundPool for older API      versions
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void initializeDeprecatedAPISoundPool() {
        // Initialize SoundPool.
        this.soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
    }

    /**     
     * Load Sounds into the SoundPool.     
     */
    private void loadIntoSoundPool() {
        //todo: finish loadIntoSoundPool() method

        // Loads all sounds from array

        // Sound 0.
        this.soundPool.load(this.context, R.raw.blip_select2, 0);

        // Sound 1.
        //this.soundPool.load(context, R.raw.sound, 1);
    }

    /**
     * Set the initial SoundPool.     
     *  Call to Method differs dependent on API Version.     
     */
    public void setInitialSoundPool() {

        // Initialize SoundPool, call specific dependent on SDK Version
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            initializeRecentAPISoundPool();
        }
        else {
            initializeDeprecatedAPISoundPool();
        }

        this.soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
                loaded = true;
                soundPool.load(context, R.raw.blip_select2, 0);
            }
        });

        // Load sounds into sound pool from resources.
        //this.loadIntoSoundPool();

    }

    /**
     * Plays the sound
     * @param id - the sound id
     * @param context - the context
     */
    public void playSound(int id, final Context context) {
        // Create Audio Manager using Context.

        soundPool.play(id, this.volume, this.volume, 1, 0, 1f);


        // Play GameSound from GameSound Pool with defined Volumes.


        Log.e("SoundPool", "Game GameSound Played");
    }
}</code>
```

Does any guys meet this issue?Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: slight off-topic: I see that this is a school project, is your professor asking for javadoc on your global variables? If not, get rid of those. Right now they don't provide more information than what your declarations already show. If yes, you should improve on them.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you David Wasser :)

I would just like to share the final implementation with you all as for what currently works with API 21 and Lower.

**As found when building SoundPool for API 21 + you have to first create AudioAttributes:**

```
    Log.d("Sound", "Initialize Audio Attributes.");
    // Initialize AudioAttributes.
    AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
            .build();
```

**Following building AudioAttributes, you then initialise SoundPool with Sound.Builder:**

```
    Log.d("Sound", "Set AudioAttributes for SoundPool.");
    // Set the audioAttributes for the SoundPool and specify maximum number of streams.
    soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
            .setAudioAttributes(attributes)
            .setMaxStreams(7)
            .build();
```

**Please note that as David Wasser pointed out, this AudioAttributes must be in a separate class to that of the default class for handing sound as AudioAttributes is not known to API 21 - Compatible Devices and thus will report in an error. I created a class for the API 21 SoundPool and AudioAttributes implementation:**

**SoundRecent.java**

```
    import android.annotation.TargetApi;
    import android.media.AudioAttributes;
    import android.media.SoundPool;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.util.Log;

    /**
     * Created by michaelstokes on 17/05/15.
     */
    public class SoundRecent {

        /**         
         * Initialize the SoundPool for later API versions
         */
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        public SoundPool initializeRecentAPISoundPool(SoundPool soundPool) {

        Log.d("Sound", "Initialize Audio Attributes.");
        // Initialize AudioAttributes.
        AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build();

        Log.d("Sound", "Set AudioAttributes for SoundPool.");
        // Set the audioAttributes for the SoundPool and specify maximum number of streams.
        soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
                .setAudioAttributes(attributes)
                .setMaxStreams(7)
                .build();

        return soundPool;
    }
}
```

**For your original SoundClass where the checking of the Devices API Version and thus the appropriate initialiser will be called: **

```
    package thedronegame.group08.surrey.ac.uk.thedronegame;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by Michael on 19/03/15.
 */
public class Sound {

    /**
     * The sound pool
     */
    private SoundPool soundPool = null;


    /**
     * The current Sound.
     */
    private int sound = 0;

    /**
     * false Boolean.
     */
    private boolean loaded = false;

    /**
     * The context.
     */
    private Context context = null;

    /**
     * Audio Manager.
     */
    private AudioManager audioManager = null;

    /**
     * Literal Volume.
     */
    private float literalVolume = 0;

    /**
     * Maximum Volume.
     */
    private float maximumVolume = 0;

    /**
     * Volume.
     */
    private float volume = 0;

    /**
     * A constructor for creating a new Sound object
     */
    public Sound(Context context) {

        this.context = context;

        this.audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        // Set Literal Volume for Audio Manager.
        this.literalVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        // Set Maximum Volume for Audio Manager.
        this.maximumVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        // Set volume for GameSound Pool.
        this.volume = literalVolume / maximumVolume;

    }

    /**     
     * Initialize the SoundPool for later API versions
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void initializeRecentAPISoundPool() {

        Log.d("SoundPool", "Initialize recent API Sound Pool");
        this.soundPool = new SoundRecent().initializeRecentAPISoundPool(this.soundPool);
    }

    /**     
     * Intialize SoundPool for older API      versions
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void initializeDeprecatedAPISoundPool() {
        // Initialize SoundPool.
        this.soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    }

    /**     
     * Load Sounds into the SoundPool.     
     */
    private void addSoundsToSoundPool() {

        Log.d("Sound", "Load Sounds.");

        int soundID = 0;

        // Load Sound 1
        soundID = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.blip_select2, 1);
        Log.d("Sound", "Sound " + soundID + " Loaded.");

        // Load Sound 2
        soundID = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.pickup_coin3, 1);
        Log.d("Sound", "Sound " + soundID + " Loaded.");

        // Load Sound 3
        soundID = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.explosion2, 1);
        Log.d("Sound", "Sound " + soundID + " Loaded.");

        // Load Sound 4
        soundID = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.powerup8, 1);
        Log.d("Sound", "Sound " + soundID + " Loaded.");

        // Load Sound 5
        soundID = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.powerup15, 1);
        Log.d("Sound", "Sound " + soundID + " Loaded.");

        // Load Sound 6
        soundID = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.jump9, 1);
        Log.d("Sound", "Sound " + soundID + " Loaded.");

        // Load Sound 7
        soundID = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.powerup18, 1);
        Log.d("Sound", "Sound " + soundID + " Loaded.");
    }

    /**
     * Set the initial SoundPool.     
     *  Call to Method differs dependent on API Version.     
     */
    public void setInitialSoundPool() {

        Log.d("Sound", "Initialize Recent or Deprecated API SoundPool.");

        // Initialize SoundPool, call specific dependent on SDK Version
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Log.d("Sound", "Initialize Recent API SoundPool.");
            initializeRecentAPISoundPool();
        }
        else {
            Log.d("Sound", "Initialize Old API SoundPool.");
            initializeDeprecatedAPISoundPool();
        }

        this.soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
                loaded = true;
            }
        });

        // Add and Load sounds into SoundPool.
        this.addSoundsToSoundPool();
    }

    /**
     * Plays the sound
     * @param id - the sound id
     * @param context - the context
     */
    public void playSound(int id, final Context context) {

        Log.d("Sound", "Play GameSound " + id + 1 + ".");
        soundPool.play(id + 1, this.volume, this.volume, 1, 0, 1f);
        Log.d("Sound", "GameSound " + id + 1 + " Played");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to support older API levels, you need to encapsulate the code you have in `initializeRecentAPISoundPool()` into a separate class. When your `Sound` class is loaded, the class loader checks that all the classes it references also exist (it doesn't load them, it just checks that they exist). In your case, on older API levels, the class `AudioAttributes$Builder` does not exist, so the class loader fails to load your `Sound` class.

The way around this is to move the code that is only supported in newer API levels into a separate class and only instantiate (or use) that class when you know that you are running on a device that has at least that API level.

You are already doing this correctly by checking the API level and calling 2 different methods, depending on the API level of the device. To make this work you just need to move the code out into a separate class.

NOTE: Interestingly, this isn't a problem when using newer **methods** of an existing class. The class loader doesn't check that all the methods you are referencing exist when it loads a class.